# $\dot{H}^1\subset L^6 $

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am reading about Lebesgue space and Sobolev spaces that are homogeneous.
An exercise that my professor gave me is: How can I use the Sobovev's inject to demonstrate that

$$\dot{H}^1(\mathbb{R}^3)\subset L^6(\mathbb{R}^3) ?$$

I was thinking in to use the respective norms, but I cannot solve it.

Comment: Should this be on ${\mathbb R}^3$ (instead of ${\mathbb R}$) ?

Comment: @Yuval yes, I already corrected the question. Thanks

Comment: which sobolev injects do you know ?

Comment: Please can you give the definition of $\dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^3)$? This could mean a few different things.

Answer (score 1):

For $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, a bounded open subset with regular  boundary, if $u \in H^1(\Omega) = W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, using Evans-2010, Theorem 6, page 284 we have $u \in L^{q}(\Omega)$, where $1/q = 1/2 - 1/3$. Note that $q = 6$. The case $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^{3}$ can be found in Kesavan S.Topics in functional analysis and applications.(2003), in the page  79, Theorem 2.4.5.